# How to find out if ClamAV current version has signature for specific Exploit/Trojan/Worm etc. or not?

Tags: antivirus, cve

I installed ClamAV(version 0.99.2/23581/Thu Jul 20 16:15:14 2017) and updated the installation to have latest signatures. I found on this website (https://lists.gt.net/clamav/virusdb/69755?page=last) that signature for Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_0266-6311814-0 was added in version 23382.

Is there any way to find out if my version of ClamAV has signature to detect Html.Exploit.CVE_2017_0266-6311814-0 or any other specific detection signature, given that every new update can drop/ignore previous signatures?